# Как сделать чтобы внутренние отступы блока "container" в bootstrap не действовали на первый дочерний блок?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать чтобы внутренние отступы блока "container" в bootstrap не действовали на первый дочерний блок, а на остальные действовал как обычно. То есть первый блок должен иметь ширину на весь размер контейнера.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-block">
    <img src="/some/url">
  </div>
  <div class="second-block">
    some content...
  </div>
  <div class="third-block">
    some content...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вариант 1

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-block row">
    some content...
  </div>
  <div class="second-block">
    some content...
  </div>
  <div class="third-block">
    some content...
  </div>
</div>
```

вариант 2

```css
.container > div:first-child{
  margin: 0 -15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-block">
    some content...
  </div>
  <div class="second-block">
    some content...
  </div>
  <div class="third-block">
    some content...
  </div>
</div>
```